# ¿Cuál es el significado de estas líneas en postgreSQL?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy en mi primer trabajo como desarrolladora, y sé algo de postgres, pero las funciones almacenadas son algo que no domino. Les muestro estas líneas:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TRUE FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='tabla_generaciondemovimientos')
THEN
INSERT INTO tabla_generaciondemovimientos VALUES('F1-Inicia proceso de generación en el archivo',now());
END IF;
```

Por lo que entiendo, allí dice que si existe pg_tables, en la cual el nombre de tablename es igual a tabla_generaciondemovimientos, entonces que inserte en la tabla_generaciondemovimientos los siguientes valores o más bien dicho, a F1. Mis dudas es qué es en sí esto de SELECT TRUE, y so de en VALUES, que aparece F1.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta insertando en una tabla, pero antes verifica que esta exista...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pregunta no es sí existe pg_tables eso ya lo sabe debido a que es la tabla donde se almacenan todas las tablas de una base de datos y sus propiedades, es por eso que pregunta si está registrado en pg_tables la tabla con el nombre tabla_generaciondemovimientos para conocer su existencia. Ahora el TRUE lo agregan para que sirva de respuesta al IF en caso de su existencia, en caso contrario devolverá vacío lo que es diferente a TRUE y no entra  al IF.

Lo de VALUES simplemente son los valores del insert, estos dependen del flujo que estes manejando.